# Check if value exist in array index PHP

Tags: php

I have array structure something like this:

```
 $arr =Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Monday
                [1] => Tuesday
                [2] => Wednesday
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Friday
                [1] => Saturday
                [2] => Sunday
            )

    );
```

Now i want ti check whether a value exist at certain array index 0 or 1.

```
$result=in_array('Wednesday', in_array($arr[0])) ? 'Y' : 'N';
```

I should get Y here.
When i use 1

```
$result=in_array('Friday', in_array($arr[1])) ? 'Y' : 'N';
```

i should get Y.

Comment: why two `in_array` calls ? I think `$result=in_array('Wednesday', $arr[0]) ? 'Y' : 'N'; ` is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : bool
```

The method returns a boolean, you shouldn't nest the calls because the haystack will become a `bool`.

```
$result=in_array('Wednesday', $arr[0]) ? 'Y' : 'N';
```